# Scheduling email resends in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, send-email

I'm looking for a way of scheduling an email resend in Marketing Cloud. Currently, we re-send to non-opens for some emails, by creating a filter with Measures and Data Filters to get the data of who did not open the email. This requires a little bit of manual work and generally is only done when requested by the account manager.

Is there any way, at the point of sending it for the first time, to schedule an automatic re-send for a few days time, so it automatically sends to anyone who didn't open the first one?

We've done something similar in journey builder, but that requires setting up a whole journey and isn't really practical for one-shot emails with resends.

Answer (score 1):

Not without spending more time than you currently do to do this.

Without using Journey Builder you'd need to create a scheduled automation using either queries or your data filters.

After setting that up you'd still need to manually edit this automation each time to include the "new" campaign in either the query or by adding the new data filter.

If you feed back any automated reports on clicks/opens I'd recommend looking at external options particularly in regards to how this data is fed in to see if you can filter this there.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found is by exporting a list with those who did not open the email. Then you should create a DE with that list

[image]